# data retrieving error on my post.html.erb file

Tags: html, mysql, ruby-on-rails

First of all, I'm sorry that I can't specify my problem because I couldn't find out what is the exact cause of the problem.

/db/migrate/XXXXXX_create_restaurants.rb

```
...
t.string :restaurant_name
t.string :restaurant_addr
...
```

/app/controllers/restaurant.rb

```
def post
  @restaurant = Restaurant.where(name: params[:rest_name])
end
```

/app/views/restaurant/post.html.erb

```
 ....
 <%= @restaurant.restaurant_addr %>
 ....
```

I had this "Restaurant table" and it did work well, which means that restaurant's address was showing by the way it was saved in Restaurant table. But I made a huge mistake(my guess) by making "RestaurantAddr table" after that.... I shouldn't have done that.(that table RestaurantAddr can be the same as table Restaurant's column name restaurant_addr....)

/app/models/restaurant.rb

```
...
has_one :restaurant_addr
...
```

/db/migrate/XXXXX_create_restaurant_addrs.rb

```
t.integer :restaurant_id
t.string :addr_name
t.string :addr_code
```

/app/models/restaurant_addr.rb

```
belongs_to :restaurant
```

So like above, I changed my restaurant model and added new "RestaurantAddr table". It worked well without any problem, but suddenly my web page's address was showing like

```
< RestaurantAddr0012854(some characters and numbers) >
```

when I used some RestaurantAddr tables to find Restaurant records in my controller file. So I erased that code which was related with RestaurantAddr table. Even after that, my view file's address was not showing what I intended(still that above bizarre address? thing). So I deleted my RestaurantAddr table. Then this time, when I see my post page on my website, error messages pop up saying

> "ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Search#posts" "Could not find table
>   'restaurant_addrs'."

I think my problem is that my web changed the way to retrieve data. Originally

```
<%= @restaurant.restaurant_addr %>
```

it meant restaurant_addr column of Restaurant table but now it's looking for RestaurantAddr table rather than Restaurant table.

Please, anyone can help? I can't drop all my data and reset... I'm so newbie so I didn't make "up and down migration thing". If you know what keyword can help me to search this problem and fix it, please let me know. All your comments will be a huge help for me. Thank you.

Comment: Did you remove the `has_one :restaurant_addr` from your model?

Comment: Wooow,,,, I wrote this question for 30 minutes struggling but you made a right answer for me very quick. Thank you so much!!!! It's too shame to ask this low level problem... But Thank you too much!

Comment: one problem is that you define the column `restaurant_name` and then do a search on `name` (not restaurant_name) - `@restaurant = Restaurant.where(name: params[:rest_name])`

Comment: Oh, thank you @MaxWilliams. I typed these all question, so it was just a problem in typing. But thank you!

Comment: You're welcome @JeongbinKim! Since that was the issue I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you need to remove the `has_one :restaurant_addr` from your model.